# Problems installing p2os on hydro

Tags: ros, p2os, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new at ROS and I'm trying to install p2os so I can just move my Pioneer. While following the setup tutorial (htt.p://wiki.ros.org/p2os-vanderbilt/Tutorials/Setup), at this step "cd src && git clone htt.p://www.hmt-git.com/p2os.git" i got this message "error: Failed connect to [www.hmt-git.com:80;](http://www.hmt-git.com:80;) Connection refused while accessing htt.p://www.hmt-git.com/p2os.git/info/refs". Any suggestions?

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125446/problems-installing-p2os-on-hydro/) by [NullX4](https://answers.ros.org/users/11546/nullx4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Use the official repository allen https://github.com/allenh1/p2os
use this command
git clone https://github.com/allenh1/p2os

---

Originally posted by [AndresCH](https://answers.ros.org/users/6681/andresch/) with karma: 26 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NullX4](https://answers.ros.org/users/11546/nullx4/) on 2014-03-08**:
Thanks, it worked!